# Python configparser getting and setting without exceptions

Tags: python, configparser

Everytime you try to get or set to a section using `configparser` in Python it throws a `NoSectionError` if the section does not exist. Is there anyway to avoid this?
Also, can I also avoid the `NoOptionError` when getting an option?

For example, using a dictionary, there is the `setdefault` option: instead of throwing a `KeyError` when the key does not exist, the dictionary adds the key, sets the key's value to the default value, and returns the default value.

I am currently doing the following for getting attributes:

```
def read_config(section):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(location)
    try:
        apple = config.get(section, 'apple')
    except NoSectionError, NoOptionError:
        apple = None
    try:
        pear = config.get(section, 'pear')
    except NoSectionError, NoOptionError:
        pear = None
    try:
        banana = config(section, 'banana')
    except NoSectionError, NoOptionError:
        banana = None
    return apple, pear, banana
```

And the following for setting them:

```
def save_to_config(section, apple, pear, banana):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    if not os.path.exists(folder_location):
        os.makedirs(folder_location)

    config.read(location)
    if section not in config.sections():
        config.add_section(section)

    config.set(section, 'apple', apple)
    config.set(section, 'pear', pear)
    config.set(section, 'banana', banana)
```

Setting isn't too bad because they all have the same section, but getting is well... terrible. There has got to be a better way.

Is there perhaps some one liner where I can reduce this:

```
try:
    apple = config.get(section, 'apple')
except NoSectionError, NoOptionError:
    apple = None
```

to this:

```
apple = config.get_with_default(section, 'apple', None)
```

-- EDIT --

I have tried to make the following changes per lego's suggestion:

```
def read_config(section):
    defaults = { section : {'apple': None,
                            'pear': None,
                            'banana': None }} 
    config = configparser.ConfigParser(defaults = defaults)
    config.read(location)

    apple = config.get(section, 'apple')
    pear = config.get(section, 'pear')
    banana = config(section, 'banana')

    return apple, pear, banana
```

But this still raises a `NoSectionError` if the section doesn't exist

Note: I have also tried it where defaults = just `{'apple': None, 'pear': None, 'banana': None }`  (no section)

Comment: what python version are you using? Python3/Python2?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelkader Both. It needs to be compatible with both versions. But this test was done with 2.7

Comment: I'll update my answer with this error. Just want to point out that my alternate suggestion works as well, if you're interested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative approach:

[ConfigParser.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.get) offers a `vars` parameter that can be passed in, which is used as the primary lookup if it's provided, however, it ignores whether there exists a value for the option already on the section.

We can, therefore, use `vars` via ducktyping, but we'll change the behavior of `.items()` to the following:

- If the config object has the option we're already looking for, we'll
  take that.
- Otherwise, we'll return the default from `vars`.

Here's a very naive implementation:

```py
class DefaultOption(dict):

    def __init__(self, config, section, **kv):
        self._config = config
        self._section = section
        dict.__init__(self, **kv)

    def items(self):
        _items = []
        for option in self:
            if not self._config.has_option(self._section, option):
                _items.append((option, self[option]))
            else:
                value_in_config = self._config.get(self._section, option)
                _items.append((option, value_in_config))
        return _items
```

In usage:

```py
def read_config(section, location):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(location)
    apple = config.get(section, 'apple',
                       vars=DefaultOption(config, section, apple=None))
    pear = config.get(section, 'pear',
                      vars=DefaultOption(config, section, pear=None))
    banana = config.get(section, 'banana',
                        vars=DefaultOption(config, section, banana=None))
    return apple, pear, banana

def save_to_config(section, location, apple, pear, banana):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    config.read(location)
    if section not in config.sections():
        config.add_section(section)

    config.set(section, 'apple', apple)
    config.set(section, 'pear', pear)
    with open(location, 'wb') as cf:
        config.write(cf)
```

That being said, this is a little indirect, but perfectly valid.

Note, that this will still raise `NoSectionError`.

If you're trying to handle that as well, [ConfigParser.ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser) takes a `dict_type` parameter, so you just instantiate the class with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

So, change `configparser.ConfigParser()` to `configparser.ConfigParser(dict_type=lambda: defaultdict(list))`

For all intents and purposes though, I'd probably use Lego's suggestions.

### Update for original question edit

If you want to use the `defaults` keyword into ConfigParser, it might help to look at how the implementation is defined. Here's the [`ConfigParser.__init__()` code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l241) for how defaults are initialized. You'll see that defaults are used completely differently than sections. To dive a bit deeper about the role they play during `get()`, look at the code for [`ConfigParser.get()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l604). Basically, if the section isn't [`DEFAULTSECT`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l105), then a `NoSectionError` is thrown.

You have two ways to overcome this:

1. Use the `defaultdict` idea I proposed above
2. Modify your `read_config` function slightly

```py
def read_config(section):
    defaults = {'apple': None,
                'pear': None,
                'banana': None }
    config = configparser.ConfigParser(defaults = defaults)
    config.read(location)
    if not config.has_section(section):
        config.add_section(section)

    apple = config.get(section,'apple')
    pear = config.get(section, 'pear')
    banana = config.get(section, 'banana')

    return apple, pear, banana
```

But I say, since this is not a one-liner, it opens up a lot more paths like the `DefaultOption` class I offered. We can make it even a bit less verbose.

Answer (score 12):

There a few ways to handle this depending on how complex you want to get.

The simplest way is probably just chaining logic together. `ConfigParser` defines [`has_option`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.has_option) to safely check if an option exists for a section.

```
apple = config.has_option(section,'apple') and config.get(section,'apple') or None
```

Alternatively, if you know ahead of time which options should have values you can set the [`defaults`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser) dictionary when instantiating the parser. This has the advantage of retaining and raising any errors for sections you don't know about.

```
 myDefaults = {'apple':None,'banana':None,'pear':None}
 config = configparser.ConfigParser(defaults=myDefaults)
```

As stated by Wogan you can create a wrapper function, but you can easily just again use `has_option` like so:

```
def get_with_default(config,section,name,default)
    if config.has_option(section,name):
        return config.get(section,name)
    else:
        return default
```

Comment: turns out this doesn't work. Even with the defaults, I get a no section error. Is there something missing?

Comment: I've offered 3 separate alternatives and links to the documentation, if its still not working I'd suggest expanding your question with more details and actual code along with what ever updates you've made.

Comment: Added my changes to the bottom of my question

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you already have your answer in your question:

```
def get_with_default(section, name, default)
    try:
        return config.get(section, name)
    except (NoSectionError, NoOptionError):
        return default
```

An alternative could be to set up a `dict` with defaults for each section and call `read_dict(defaults)` on the configparser before loading your configuration from the file. This should ensure no section is missing & therefore no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a wrapper function to have the `dict.setdefault` behavior if that's what you want:

```
def config_setdefault_get(config, section, key, default)
    result = default
    try:
        result = config.get(section, key)
    except NoSectionError:
        config.add_section(section)
        config.set(section, key, default)
    except NoOptionError:
        config.set(section, key, default)
    finally:
        return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Handling the exception in a wrapper function is probably more efficient.  If you must avoid the exception handling, a compound `if` does the trick.

```
def get_with_default(section,name,default):
    return config.get(section,name) if config.has_section(section) and config.has_option(section, name) else default
```

Comment: Couple of typos...   Missing Colon on the function def and "option" should be "name" on the last IF.   But it does work once those are fixed.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about not repeating yourself? Then it's less of a hassle when you have to catch errors.

```
def read_config(section, default=None, *vars):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(location)
    ret = []
    for var in vars:
        try:
            ret.append(config.get(section, var))
        except NoSectionError, NoOptionError:
            ret.append(default)
    return ret
```

Aw yes, Wogan already solved it this way...